# Material choice / optical properties for solar panel cover (glass/perspex/lexan)

Tags: solar-cell, optoelectronics, materials

First off I realise this is sort-of off-topic but this was the most relevant stack site I could think of...

I have a Bosch solar panel which was damaged by couriers, the glass covering was shattered but the panel underneath is fine.

So, I was just about to buy a sheet of something (probably standard glazing perspex) to replace it, but wondered what the optical properties of the solar panel/cells actually are - if putting the wrong glass or plastic in front of it could block certain wavelengths that the panel find most useful.

Any info greatly appreciated!

Edit to add: It's going to be mounted on a vehicle and I'd rather not use glass for that as getting hold of suitably toughened glass is not as easy or cheap as perspex/lexan/makrolon etc.

Comment: I would not try to fix this, I **guarantee** you that you will get problems with **moisture** getting inside the panel. If there is a way, water will find that way. As far as I know the glass is just ordinary glass, nothing special. I would not use perspex as this might discolor/turn opaque due to UV from the sun. Why not simple have the courier (or their insurance) replace the panel?

Comment: It's already been replaced for free, the seller didn't want the broken one back so I have a "free" panel, hence repairing it would be a nice bonus. I have access to marine-grade sealants and epoxies and am willing to take the risk for a free panel.

Comment: OK, in that case, I would do the same.

Comment: I seem to remember that it is usually a low iron type glass and also resistant to impacts (as birds have been known to drop things on them...) Are you talking about photovoltaic or Solar Thermal panels? If solar thermal, there are perspex covers available (FilSol used them with a "pillow" shape to stop sagging as they can get hot...

Comment: Sorry, should have said PV panels. I'm hoping to avoid glass due to the (relative) difficulty of sourcing suitable glass cut to size compared with plastics, and the fact it's on the roof of a 4x4 so subject to motorway speeds, tree branches, and a bit of vibration/flex.